# How to find copy constructor in constructor array

Tags: java, generics, reflection, abstract-class, copy-constructor

I am using the getConstructors() method to pull the  class's contructors. The class is in an abstract superclass reference, and I won't know which subclass is being called until the user decides. Here's what I have so far.

```
Weapon stickCopy = stick;
System.out.println(stick);
System.out.println(stickCopy);

Class <? extends Weapon> myClass = stick.getClass( );

System.out.println(myClass.getSimpleName( ));

Constructor<?>[] construct = myClass.getConstructors( );

for(Constructor<?> constructor: construct)
{
    System.out.println(constructor);
}

try
{
    stickCopy = (Weapon) construct[2].newInstance((stick));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(stick);
System.out.println(stickCopy);
```

The Stick class is a subclass of the abstract Weapon class. I am trying to figure out the code for a deep copy from a Weapon reference, stored in a player object. Since Weapon is abstract, I can't call a copy constructor from it. In my Stick class, the copy constructor is the third constructor, and so I hard-coded 2 into the construct array in the try statement. If I change the stick class's constructors by, say, adding a new constructor in front of the copy constructor or reordering them, how can I find the position of the copy constructor at run-time?

Also, I have never used Generics before, so, if I am not following what are generally considered good programming practices, please correct me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure using reflection for this is a good idea. You might want to consider adding a `public abstract Weapon deepCopy()` method to your `Weapon` class, which then each subclass has to implement?

Comment: @biziclop
I think I see why your suggestion might be a better idea, but I don't know how I would implement it. I have a Weapon attribute in my player class that holds an arbitrary subclass, such as Stick. I would like to write my getter so that it does a copy instead of passing out the reference. Would it be like this? `public Weapon getWeapon() { return weapon.deepCopy(); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [the version of getConstructor that takes arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) you can specify the constructor you want by its argument types.  Presumably you'll want to pass either Stick.class or Weapon.class in:

```
Constructor constructor = myClass.getConstructor(myClass);
```

Comment: The parameter must be an array, IIRC, but otherwise the cleanest solution.

Comment: @Jochen It's varargs now, happy days.

Comment: I do have a follow-up question. Would there be a situation where my try-catch statement surrounding your code actually throw an error if I make sure weapon is not null? I'm trying to decide whether I should use a try/catch or pass it up the stack.

Comment: @Gilbrithor, just note that while this is a good way to identify the signature of a "copy-constructor", that does not really guarantee that the so-called copy constructor actually performs a deep copy.

Comment: @kevin I think I understand what you are saying. If I ensure the copy constructors perform deep copies, I wouldn't have to worry about this. But, if someone else derives a class and doesn't perform a deep copy, then I could be in trouble?

Comment: @Gilbrilthor Exactly. And even if you're writing everything, in practice you'll make mistakes. What typically happens is that you add a new field but forget to add a line to the copy constructor to copy that field.

Answer (score 2):

Costructor.getParameterTypes() tells you the types the parameters the constructor takes. So check for the one that takes an Object of the correct type.